# Embedding syntax in Ace editor

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ace-editor

Code https://codesandbox.io/embed/epic-tu-q5jj0

My goal is to stop Ace editor (JSON mode) complaining about multi-line JavaScript code if the code is assigned to the "script" key and surrounded by triple-double quotes.

The editor value:

```
{
  "id": 0,
  "script": """
   function add(x, y) {
      return x + y;
   }
   add(1, 2);
   """,
   "descr": "add two numbers"
}
```

The error:

[image]

Basically, the error shouldn't be visible.

As far as I understand, I need a custom mode. There is [a guide about how to create the custom mode](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Creating-or-Extending-an-Edit-Mode) but I can't make it work.

I tried extending JSON mode and adding my rules for the triple-quotes:

```
import "brace/mode/json";

const JsonMode = window.ace.acequire("ace/mode/json").Mode;

export default class JsonCodeMode extends JsonMode {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.$rules = {
      start: [
        {
          token: "string", // multi line """ string start
          regex: '("source"|"script")(\\s*?):(\\s*?)"{3}',
          next: "qqstring3"
        },
        {
          token: "text",
          regex: "\\s+"
        }
      ],
      qqstring3: [
        {
          token: "string", // multi line """ string end
          regex: '"{3}',
          next: "start"
        },
        {
          defaultToken: "string"
        }
      ]
    };

    console.log("JsonTextCodeMode rules", this.$rules);
  }
}
```

Also, I tried embedding JavaScript highlight rules but got `TypeError _this.embedRules is not a function`:

```
import "brace/mode/json";

const JsonMode = window.ace.acequire("ace/mode/json").Mode;
const JavaScriptHighlightRules = window.ace.acequire(
  "ace/mode/javascript_highlight_rules"
).JavaScriptHighlightRules;

export default class JsonJSCodeMode extends JsonMode {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.HighlightRules = JavaScriptHighlightRules;

    this.$rules = {
      start: [
        {
          token: "string", // multi line """ string start
          regex: '("source"|"script")(\\s*?):(\\s*?)"{3}',
          next: "qqstring3-start"
        },
        {
          token: "text",
          regex: "\\s+"
        }
      ]
    };

    /*
    ×
      TypeError
      _this.embedRules is not a function
    */
    this.embedRules(JavaScriptHighlightRules, "qqstring3-", [
      {
        token: "string",
        regex: '"{3}',
        next: "start"
      }
    ]);

    console.log("JsonJSCodeMode rules", this.$rules);
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I can disable all errors by `this.editor.getSession().setUseWorker(false);`. But it would be nicer to develop a custom worker. This worker will handle JSON syntax and JS syntax inside the triple-quotes. https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Syntax-validation